# Creating a LiveCode IOS standalone application

Tags: xcode, ios5, ios6, livecode

I just started to use LiveCode and tried to create a standalone IOS app and get the following error:

```
"There was an error while saving the standalone application performing 
iOS device builds requires the iOS 5.0 SDK platform to be installed"
```

We are using Xcode version 4.5.1 which includes the IOS 6 SDK along with LiveCode version 5.5.1 and thought that all needed SDK's would be installed when we installed Xcode.

We also don't know where to get the IOS 5.0 SDK and how to get it installed in Xcode so LiveCode can use it.

Comment: Go to xcode>>preferences>>Downloads and download all additional SDKs

Comment: I noticed only emulators for ios 5 and 5.1. Will installing the emulator also install the sdk's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need iOS 5 SDK if you are deploying an armv6 or universal app. If you are deploying armv7 only then you won't get this error if you have iOS 6 or 6.1 SDKs. If you do that though your app won't support older armv6 devices from iPhone 3G back. When the standalone is built LiveCode needs the SDK that the engine was built against. This is why when a new SDK comes out LiveCode won't support it until its next release. If your using LiveCode it's worthwhile getting into the habit of retaining each version of Xcode.

Comment: Worth noting that deploying armv7 only means that you don't support older devices (IIRC - original iPhone & iPhone 3G, plus iPod touch up to the 3rd generation model).

Answer (score 2):

Try upgrading to Xcode 4.5.2 and then take a look at this link: http://forums.runrev.com/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=9339

Comment: FYI I was able to build a standalone for iOS using LiveCode 5.5.2 and Code 4.2. Before installing another XCode version, please try upgrading to LC 5.5.2 first. There was a problem with 5.5.1 that's fixed in 5.5.2, while it may still not work with the latest XCode that's installed in the application folder instead of the developer folder.